# Wordpress Featured Image metabox not displaying in screen options

Tags: php, wordpress

So... I've been trying to figure this out all morning, I can't get featured images to display for posts in Wordpress. This is a newly updated (4.2.1) install, and the first time trying to add this feature globally.

I tried using

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

with no luck.

I have a custom post type below where it does work set up like

```
function wp_my_custom_thing() {
    if(function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'customthing' ) );
    }
    add_image_size('customsize', 2000, 750, true);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wp_my_custom_thing');
```

but the same doesn't work for doing it globally even though it appears to execute and doesn't throw an error. Also there are no errors in the PHP log or in wp-debug

Also maybe notable, this is a multisite install, but each site has it's own theme. I've read that specifying post types like

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', 'posts' );
```

can have some issues, although I have tested it, and it also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem isn't with front end display, it's with getting it in the admin screen options, as stated in the title. I need to set featured images for use for an administrative feature that never is rendered to the front end.

Comment: The option isn't even available in the screen options drop down. It's not a hidden panel or simple missed check of a checkbox.

Comment: Again, if you read above, 'featured image' must be checked off in screen options. It's not existent there.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the checkbox isn't available to select in screen options. it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

They are turned off by default.

Go to `Network Admin` > `Settings` > `Network Settings` > `Upload Settings` and check `Media upload button`.

This line is only for your custom post type:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'customthing' ) );
```

Best just to leave it at:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
```